# How can I extract metadata from 10 000 PDF documents and store it in my database?

Tags: php, database, symfony, web-crawler

I'm currently building a document-sharing platform, and to attract as many users as possible, I want to already add 10 000 documents to my platform. The documents are only PDF files. I'm working with Symfony2, but I guess this doesn't change much to the problem: how can I extract the metadata I need from these documents (for example, title, the first 100 words for the description) automatically and insert it into my database (in my case, hydrate it into my entities, but I know that part).

I guess a crawler is what I'm looking for but I have no idea where to find something like this nor how to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried? what "documents" are you talking about? I can tell that if you mean documents in general, there is no general way to get those information. It depends on the document type  ie. `*.txt`, `*.doc`, `*.docx`, `*.rtf`, `*.pdf` etc. also images, videos or excel sheets are documents, so you will have a lot of work ;)

Comment: For now, I haven't tried anything, I'm trying to see all the options available. I'll edit to give details about the documents, you're of course right I should have detailed that earlier ^^

Comment: and you should have tried something!!! this is not a "give me working code"-platform it's more like a "where did I make a mistake"-platform ;)

Comment: I understand that, however I have no idea what to do. Someone must have experienced this kind of problem and may direct me towards the best solution. I'm not asking for having a perfect solution handed in to me, I just want to know what I could use and where to find it because my research so far has been unsuccessful in that matter.

Answer (score 1):

well as you don't have a real question:

- define what document types/formats you allow
- google for how to read each document type with php (php-functions, libraries, code-snippets)
- determine the file type of uploaded documents
- read the files in php using the googled funcs, libs etc.

when you have done all this and then have a specific problem: ask a real question ;)

Comment: I don't really understand your attitude towards this question. You were right on the document formats, and I edited to take your point into account.
I know how to read PDF files in PHP. My problem is that I don't know how to launch an automated process of scanning the files and adding the data to the database. As asked in the question.

Comment: what you mean by automated? you maybe want to create a cronjob on linux or a scheduled task on windows. use (recursive) directory iterator or glob to find the files ;)

Comment: I mean that I don't want to process each document through my upload form.
Basically, I'm looking for a way to have all my documents registered in my database without having to process them myself one by one through my form, which would take ages.

Comment: so use a cronjob or scheduled task ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time and your precious help ;)